# how to create own matrix in openCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, mat

Hi in the following link http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~ahuaman3/docs/OpenCV_Docs/tutorials/basic_0/basic_0.html  it is shown how to create a uniform matrix where all elements are 23.
How can I create a matrix of

```
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
```

in openCV. I want the user to input the no. of rows of 2. How I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
uchar mydata[]={1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1};
cv::Mat mymat(3,3,CV_8UC1,mydata);
```

mymat:

```
1 2 1
1 2 1
1 2 1
```

Comment: The OP wants to hold negative entries, so maybe you should adjust the type?

Comment: @roger rowland   what type should it be? CV_32FC1 ?

Comment: @Willam I want the user to input the no. of rows of 2. How I can do that?

Comment: @user2481422 that would certainly allow negative entries, yes, so would CV_8SC1.

Comment: @roger can you suggest me if I want the user to input the no. of rows of 2. How I can do that?

Comment: @user2481422 Constructor used here is cv::Mat(rows,cols,type,*data). You can change anything you like. Rows, cols, type.

Comment: @William no no I don't want to change the no. of rows on whole, I just to change the number of rows of 2's , like sometimes there will be two rows of 2, sometimes 4 rows of 2 n all

Comment: @william can you be more clear, I can't get the usage of std::vector

Comment: By using vector<vector<int>> mydata, you can manipulate rows and cols. Google it for more.